# Pulling Bloginfo title into external file that is embedded in WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress, include, shortcode

I have an external PHP file that I'm pulling into a WordPress post using a shortcode. I can include the file just fine but I want to use

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

in the body of the text that is included. But the problem is, the included file is not referencing the parent file to know what the bloginfo so I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function bloginfo() in /home/fluffdun/public_html/commonPages/about.php on line 4
```

The included file is on a completely different server and the reason is because we want to be able to include the same file into different blogs and have the bloginfo automatically change. So, how do I have the included file reference the parent to get this info?

Comment: The issue seems to be focused on the fact that the blog and the external files are on two different servers so my attempts to reference the parent directory is just pulling the path that the included file is in.

Comment: in the external file `include('your path/blog-hearder.php')` try this